# socialfeed.js nothing showing but not errors either

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a basic feed to show content using: [socialfeed.js](https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed) but nothing is showing and im not getting any errors.

Heres the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- Social-feed css -->
    <link href="css/jquery.socialfeed.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- font-awesome for social network icons -->
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

   <div class="social-feed-container"></div>






    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Codebird.js - required for TWITTER -->
    <script src="bower_components/codebird-js/codebird.js"></script>
    <!-- doT.js for rendering templates -->
    <script src="bower_components/doT/doT.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Moment.js for showing "time ago" and/or "date"-->
    <script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Moment Locale to format the date to your language (eg. italian lang)-->
    <script src="bower_components/moment/locale/it.js"></script>
    <!-- Social-feed js -->
    <script src="js/jquery.socialfeed.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.social-feed-container').socialfeed({
                twitter:{
                accounts: ['@jquery'],                      //Array: Specify a list of accounts from which to pull tweets
                limit: 2,                                   //Integer: max number of tweets to load
                consumer_key: 'qzRXgkI7enflNJH1lWFvujT2P',          //String: consumer key. make sure to have your app read-only
                consumer_secret: '8e7E7gHuTwyDHw9lGQFO73FcUwz9YozT37lEvZulMq8FXaPl8O',//String: consumer secret key. make sure to have your app read-only
             },

            // GENERAL SETTINGS
                length:400,
                show_media: true,                                     //Integer: For posts with text longer than this length, show an ellipsis.
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work I did the following:

1) Run in console:

```
git clone https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed/
nano index1.html
```

2) Enter the code from your example (no changes are made)

3) Run webserver
4) Through webserver navigate to /index1.html (in my case http://localhost/Open-source/TroubleShootingSF/social-feed/index1.html), and we see the following:[image: The screenshot of Social-Feed working]